# useCollectionData returns undefined in react-firebase-hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I'm trying to query a collection using `useCollectionData` with a `where` query. However, it always returns `undefined`. Tried looking at the [docs](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore) but no luck.
Am I missing something?

```
import firebaseApp from '../firebaseConfig';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useDocumentData, useCollectionData, useCollection } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { getFirestore, doc, collection, query, where, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore';

function Console() {
    const [location, setLocation] = useLocation();
    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
    const accountId = user.id;
    
    // This works
    const [accountData] = useDocumentData(doc(firestore, 'accounts', accountId));

    // This fails
    const [messages] = useCollectionData(query(
        collection(firestore, "messages"),
        where("account", "==", accountId)
    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I added `error` variable, I printed it and figured out my issue is `Insufficient permissions` which was caused by a configuration issue in Firestore Rules.

```
const [messages, loadingMessages, error] = useCollectionData(query(
        collection(firestore, "messages"),
        where("accountUid", "==", accountId)
    ));
```